# CDG terminal transfer

Tags: air-travel

How long will it take me to go from my Icelandic Airline flight in Terminal 1 to an Air France flight to Madrid in Terminal 2? I have several flights to choose from to Madrid and want to allow for plenty of time.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer depends at what time of the day (or night), as security checks at T2 can be a mess. It will also depend on whether you have luggage to pick up and check in again.

I would say the timing in average would be:

- 45 mn from the time the doors open on your flight to T2 (D?) departure hall. Especially if you are not familiar with CDG.
- 30 mn for check-in and security checks.
- 20 mn before departure time.

That's about 1.5 hours. Early mornings and early evenings are very busy, and could require longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving between airlines and terminals, try and schedule 3 hours between the flights, especially if you're not familiar with the airport and have checked luggage. When I travel, I allow 2.5 hours at the absolute minimum for international flights, and 1.5 hours for domestic.